# Excel - How to do I reference a cell next to a cell with an x in it in another sheet?

Tags: match, vlookup, offset

In sheet 1 column 1 is a vertical list of words (e.g. A1:A25).

In sheet 1 column 2 I want to randomly put an X (e.g. in one cell between B1:B25)

In sheet 2 I want to return whatever word is to the left of the X in sheet 1.
How would I do this?

Comment: If the "X" was on the left you could use VLOOKUP on Sheet2, but if it is on the right you need INDEX and MATCH: `=INDEX(A1:A25,MATCH("X",B1:B25,0))`  Here are some other ways: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2453-excel-vlookup-right-to-left.html

Comment: How do I return the result to sheet 2? i.e. how do I reference sheet 1 if this code is going in sheet 2?

Comment: Got it:

=INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A25,MATCH("X",Sheet!B1:B25,0))

Thanks!

Comment: What would the formula be if I had multiple Xs in the second column? (if I wanted to pull a few of the items from column 1)?

Comment: When you say "pull a few" you mean one cell will have the first and another cell will have the second?  Or something else.

Comment: So that if there were say 10 options, a user could randomly put an x next to some, and only those would be returned with no spaces between e.g. apples, bananas and pears would be returned on rows 1, 2 and 3 in sheet 2 even though in sheet 1 they were on rows 2, 5 and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the "X" was on the left you could use VLOOKUP to find the word to it's right, but if the "X" is on the right then you need INDEX and MATCH:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$25,MATCH("X",Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25,0))
```

If you need to find the Nth "X" then you can't use that method because MATCH returns the row number of the *first* match it finds. So you need SMALL to get the Nth smallest row containing an "X":

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$25,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25="X",ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25)-ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25,1,1))+1),N))
```

Set that last "N" in the formula to the item you want to find - if it is 1 then it finds the first item with an "X" and if it is 2 it finds the second, etc.

So for the first "X":

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$25,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25="X",ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25)-ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25,1,1))+1),1))
```

And for the second:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$25,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25="X",ROW(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25)-ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$25,1,1))+1),2))
```

This is an array formula so when you type it in you need to press Control-Shift-Enter instead of just pressing Enter by itself.  After it has been entered it will be displayed with braces around it.

I adapted this formula from https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match  and they have an in-depth description of how it works.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again!

Comment: I have rows of content undr headings. e.g. In sheet 1 there might be 5 headings with 50 lines of content between each heading.How would you return to sheet 2 all headings in sheet 1 column 1 that have an x beside them in sheet 1 column 2? That is, without having 150 rows of space in column 2? e.g. if 3 of the 5 headings have an x beside them, those 3 headings are returned, on only 3 rows.

Comment: @legosquares  How do you identify the headings?  If they are all in column 1 there needs to be a way to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

Vlookup is taking from left to right. If you exchange columns in sheet 1, you can use `=vlookup()` formula.